# Entity Framework Code First one-to-one relation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, poco

I'm trying to create a one-to-one relation between two tables, but as a result I have one-to-many. What is the problem with this code?

```
namespace EFCF_Demo.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string MiniContent { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public virtual Content MainContent { get; set; }   
    }

    public class Content
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        public string FullContent { get; set; }
    }

    public class PostEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see KeyAttribute in Content class.

Comment: Key is detecting automatically by EFCF and it's - ID. I resolve this with fluent API but steel have some problems with saving Content.

Comment: if I am not wrong, When the property is named Id, or ClassNameId, it is presumed to be the primary key

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need PostId in the Content class, and ContentId in the Post class?

```
        public class Content
        {
            [Key]
            public int PostId { get; set; }
            public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
            public string FullContent { get; set; }
        }
```

what about this:) This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was resolved by removing

```
public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
```

After that we don't need to use the Fluent API but I have some problems with saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/4b5a46e0-f5c2-4c38-a73c-0038eaef2537
- [How to declare one to one relationship using Entity Framework 4 Code First (POCO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco)