# EF 4.1 one to one Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have two tables Employees and Positions.

### Employee

EmployeeId (PK)

PositionId (FK, Nullable)

### Position

PositionId (PK)

A position can be created and not be assigned. However, an active employee requires a position. A position can only be assigned to one employee. We enforce this by having a Unique Constraint on Employee.PositionId.

In my models, I want to have an Employee property in Position and I am having issues mapping this.

I've tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasRequired(e => e.Position)
                               .WithOptional(p => p.Employee);
```

However this ends up mapping the Employee.EmployeeId to Position.PositionId column, instead of Employee.PositionId to Position.PositionId (at least from what I can tell...)

Is my only option to make map this as a One to Many relationship even though I am forcing 1-1 through unique constraint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare one to one relationship using Entity Framework 4 Code First (POCO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

> Code First (and EF in general) does not natively support one-to-one foreign key associations. In fact, EF does not support any association scenario that involves unique constraints at all.

In fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Position)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.PositionId);
```

Then override the `Seed` method:

```
protected override void Seed(EntityMappingContext context)
{
context.Database.SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Employees ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Position UNIQUE(PositionId)");
}
```