# EF5.0 ForeignKey and Unique Constraint

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, unique, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables with below structures

A{Impid(PK),name,code,etc.....)
B(Id(PK),Impid(FK && Unique),some columns)..

Basically its a one to one relationship (extension of table A columns).

I am trying to use in EF. could some one please help me setting up the model configurations for it?

Comment: If you're wanting a one to one relationship, there's already a [great post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco) about that

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't support unique constraint so you must either change your DB and put FK on Id in B or you must map it as one-to-many and expose navigation property only on B (because on A you would need a collection of Bs).