# Multiplicity not allowed. Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to use MVC4 for the first time and am receiving the following error when I try to create a controller?  Could someone kindly steer me in the right direction?

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid
>   in Role 'PropertyData_DNISData_Target' in relationship
>   'PropertyData_DNISData'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not
>   the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

```
public class PropertyData
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string PropertyID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("DNISData")]
    public virtual string DNIS { get; set; }

    public virtual string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string PropertyGreeting { get; set; }
    public virtual string PropertyOperator { get; set; }
    public virtual string InvalidEntryPrompt { get; set; }
    public virtual string NoEntryPrompt { get; set; }
    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual DNISData DNISData { get; set; }

}

public class DNISData
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string DNIS { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PropertyData")]
    public string PropertyID { get; set; }
    public virtual string VDN { get; set; }
    public virtual string PropertyGreeting { get; set; }
    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyData PropertyData { get; set; }
}

public class DigitData
{
    [ForeignKey ("DNISData")]
    [Key]
    public virtual string DNIS { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public virtual string Digit { get; set; }
    public virtual string InvalidEntryPrompt { get; set; }
    public virtual DNISData DNISData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a 1 to 1 relationship between PropertyData and DNISData. This can only be done via shared primarykey in EntityFramework.

This question can give you the anwser you are looking for:

[How to declare one to one relationship using Entity Framework 4 Code First (POCO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622572/how-to-declare-one-to-one-relationship-using-entity-framework-4-code-first-poco)

Comment: What is a shared primary key?

Comment: A shared primary key is that both table hold the same pk value. If table A Id is X then table B Id will also be X. [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)