# creating 1-1 relationship between two class using code first and migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Well, it is 1st time i am trying to create 1-1 relationship between two tables using code first. I took some help online and come across the following classes mapping.

Than I ran migration and found something wrong. E.g. The migration says that primary key for StudentDetails is `Id` from Student table whereas I am looking to have primary key StudentId.  Also, the foreign key is being created in opposite way.

Please can someone highlight what is wrong here or is it me who perceived it wrong.

I need to use `Id` from `student` class as Foreign key in StudentDetails class.

```
public class Student
{
    public bool isPass{get;set;}
    public virtual StudentReport Report { get; set; }
}

public class StudentReport
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? StudentReportId { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

When i run my migration, i get the following outcome which looks not good.

```
public partial class StudentReport : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
{
CreateTable(
    "dbo.StudentReport",
    c => new
    {
    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
    StudentReportId = c.Guid(),
    RollNumber = c.String(),
    StudentType = c.String(),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Student", t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Id);
}
```

Comment: Who is `StudentDetail` entity, `StudentReport`? Also, what do you mean with _the FK is being created in oposited way_? You are using the `ForeignKey` data annotation on the `Id` porperty in the `StudentReport` entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an one to one relationship one end must be the principal and the another one is the dependent.  If you are going to declare a FK property in the dependent entity, EF requires that property should be PK too:

```
public class Principal
{
   [Key]
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public virtual Dependent Dependent{get;set;}
}

public class Dependent
{
   [Key, ForeignKey("Principal")]
   public int PrincipalId{get;set;}

   public virtual Principal Principal{get;set;}
}
```

If you want to have both entities with their own PKs, and also use `Id` from `Student` entity as FK in `StudentReport` class, then you can try with this model:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool isPass{get;set;} 
}

public class StudentReport
{
    [Key]
    public Guid StudentReportId{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

I guess what you really need is an one to many relationship because an student could have 0 or many reports.

Check this [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s02.html). It could help you understand better how to use the FK properties and the name conventions that have by default Code First.

### Update 1

If you want to create an one to one relationship and both entities have their owns PKs, then you can't define a FK property in the dependent entity due to the restriction I explain at the begin of my answer. A solution for what you need could be using the `Required` attribute and deleting the FK property:

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool isPass{get;set;} 

   public virtual StudentReport StudentReport { get; set; }
}

public class StudentReport
{
    [Key]
    public Guid StudentReportId{ get; set; }

    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

### Update 2

Are you sure? The migration code that I get is this:

```
 AddForeignKey("dbo.StudentReports", "StudentReportId", "dbo.Students", "Id");
```

Which is not ok yet because Code First is still configuring by convention the PK of `StudentReport` as FK. To avoid that you can add this Fluent Api configuration to your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentReport>()
            .HasRequired(sr => sr.Student)
            .WithOptional(s => s.StudentReport)
            .Map(c=>c.MapKey("Student_Id"));
```

This way Code First will generate this migration code:

```
 AddColumn("dbo.StudentReports", "Student_Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
 CreateIndex("dbo.StudentReports", "Student_Id");
 AddForeignKey("dbo.StudentReports", "Student_Id", "dbo.Students", "Id");
```

Comment: I absolutely looking for "If you want to have both entities with their own PKs, and also use Id from Student entity as FK in StudentReport class, then you can try with this model:"  However, in your example, Why you have written public Guid? StudentId { get; set; } becuase StudentId  does not exist in parent Student class. Can you remove fluent API code because i dont need this way and it will also make your answer cleaner to help me understand.

Comment: The `StudentId` is the name you are going to give to the FK column in the `StudentReports` table, but it is related directly with the `Id` of `Students` table

Comment: @ octavioccl, thanks you. I am getting some error with your above logic "Multiplicity is not valid ..." Also, why you did not have navigation property in Student class? Is there reason behind it?

Comment: Yes, because, in the model that I show above I'm creating a unidirectional one to many relationship, omitting the navigation property in the `Student` entity.

Comment: I think it wont work as i mentioned an error in above comment and then i found the reason for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276381/multiplicity-not-allowed-entity-framework correct me if i am wrong. I am using EF 6.1.1 version

Comment: Okay, with your latest updated code... i have following line in my migrated schema .ForeignKey("dbo.Student", t => t.StudentReportId) ... This is correct? I dont think so becuase I am exexting Id from student table to be used as foreign key in StudentReport table.