# How to separate Profile information

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building an application using asp.net mvc5 with EF6. I was able to do the authentication part and even add information to the tables witch mvc5 auto-generates when we choose the Individual user accounts option. What i wanted to do now is to create a user profile. I know i can use the same table but i wanted to create another one so i can separate Authentication info from profile info. This is what i tried so far:

```
public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ProfileInfo Profile { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileInfo  : IdentityUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string apelido { get; set; }
    public string idade { get; set; }
    public string sexo { get; set; }
    public string profissao { get; set; }
    public string nacionalidade { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ProfileInfo>
{
    public ProfileDbContext()
        :base ("DefaultConnection" , throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ProfileInfo> Perfil { get; set; }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProfileInfo> ProfileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

i couldn't find information about this anywhere else. All the tutorials i see use the AspnetUser table to store profile information.

EDIT:
OK, so now i have found that what i need is just a foreignKey to the table Asp.netUsers. Problem is, the primary key from that table is a varChar... not an int. Damn Microsoft...

Comment: If you want a separate table why not use a foriegn key to `IdentityUser.Id` and the related virtual property instead of inheritance?

Comment: well thats my problem, i dont know how to do that and everything i see on the web explains how to do it using the same table :S

Comment: Sounds like you just need to configure a one-to-one relationship between an `IdentityUser` and a `ProfileInfo`. Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837964/2030565).

Comment: problem is, how do u define the foreign keys to asp.netUsers ??

Comment: You can still use varchar `IdentityUser.Id` as a FK on `ProfileInfo`. Just make `ProfileInfo.IdentityUserId` varchar (string) as well. Alternatively, but it's more work, you can change Identity to use int instead of the default string type -- there are other SO posts that cover that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, defined a relationship from `UserProfile` to `ProfileInfo`.

```
public class UserProfile : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("ProfileInfo")]
    public int ProfileInfoId Profile { get; set; }
    public ProfileInfo ProfileInfo { get;set; }
}
```